# Is it possible to include svg image in pdf document rendered by rmarkdown?

Tags: r, svg, pdf-generation, r-markdown

I want an svg image to be embedded in an pdf document that I render by using rmarkdown. This doesn't seem possible, or do I miss something? If it's not possible is there a way to first convert the .svg image to a .png before embedding it?

In my rmarkdown file it looks like this (notice the two different kinds of inserting the image):

````
```{r results="asis",eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment = NA,fig.height=10}

cat("![](svg_file.svg)")

```

![](svg_file.svg)
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. It is based on using the `svg` LaTeX package and some LaTeX code inside your Rmarkdown file.

This can be achieved in these main steps:

1. Include the `svg` package to the LaTeX preamble. This can be done using the Rmarkdown header.
2. Make sure that LaTeX is called with the `--shell-escape` option enabled. This can also be done using the Rmarkdown header.
3. Include your SVG image using `\includesvg{svg-image}` inside your Rmarkdown text. Be careful, **do not include the file extension**.

Make sure to use `pdflatex` as the LaTeX engine. Other engines will probably work as well, but they will require different options...

The following is a example that works in my machine, having a SVG image called `svg-image.svg` in the working directory.

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    pandoc_args: "--latex-engine-opt=--shell-escape"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{svg}
---

\includesvg{svg-image}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I found interesting your approach to solve this problem, but how should be done for render the plots created in the chunks?

Comment: @Riverarodrigoa. How about calling  `\includesvg{svg-image}` right after a chunk in which you created and saved the svg-image?

Comment: It should be mentioned that svg package [requires](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg) Inkscape to do that (alternatively, pandoc should [also](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1793#issuecomment-321329183) support such kind of conversion.. but it requires additional dependencies too)

Comment: Also note that enabling shell-escape with `rmarkdown` is done through the R option `tinytex.engine_args`, e. g. `options(tinytex.engine_args = '--shell-escape')`; [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660211/3930713)

Answer (score 9):

Now we can simply use the cowplot library to read an image and plot it in R markdown.

````
```{r figSvg,eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE,fig.height=10}

library(cowplot)
fig_svg<-cowplot::ggdraw()+cowplot::draw_image("http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg")
plot(fig_svg)
````

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

````
library(rsvg)
```{r fig2, fig.cap="desc"}
# Path to your SVG file
svg_file <- "Picture1.svg"

# Convert SVG to PNG (or PDF) for PDF output
pdf_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")
rsvg::rsvg_pdf(svg_file, pdf_file, )
knitr::include_graphics(pdf_file)
```
````

Comment: Your answer should be explained with some text outside the code block