# How can I include a svg file in a PDF created using Rmarkdown?

Tags: pdf, svg, r-markdown

I'm working on R Project trying to knit a PDF in Rmarkdown that includes a svg file.

First I tried:

```
![svg_figure](folder/file.svg)
```

And I got this:

! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg

Then I tried:

````
```{r figSvg,eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE,fig.height=10}
library(cowplot)
svg_figure<-cowplot::ggdraw()+cowplot::draw_image(folder/file.svg)
plot(svg_figure)
```
````

But I got a blank space in my pdf, and I had to install the 'magick' library for the image to be drawn.

And once installed, I get this error:

Error in methods::is(image,"magick-image"): object 'folder' not found

The folder does exist, and when I try adding the png file of the same visual scheme, I have no errors.

Does anyone know what might be happening or about a different method to include a svg file into a pdf in Rmarkdown?

Thanks.

Comment: The error "object 'folder' not found" is probobly because the parameter should be a string, so `...draw_image("folder/file.svg")`.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46065070/322084

Comment: Cool, that was exactly the problem @chrwahl. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to include svg image in pdf document rendered by rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064292/is-it-possible-to-include-svg-image-in-pdf-document-rendered-by-rmarkdown)

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc (the converter used by R Markdown) will try to convert the SVG using the `rsvg-convert` executable. Try to install the respective package on your system to use the simple Markdown syntax.

---

A more manual approach would be to convert the SVG to Ti*k*Z, a TeX package that works a lot like SVG. There are converters, e.g. [svg2tikz](https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz). You'd include the generated code like this:

````
```{=tex}
% TikZ code goes here
```
````

But that will probably require a lot more work, as it bypasses R Markdown and will need manual adjustments. I would only use it if you want to make sure that the image remains a vector graphic.